# Find real index file in public directory in live server. main index encrypted

Tags: html, public-html, liveserver

In my Public_html directory. there is an index file which code showing like the following screenshot:

[image: index.html screenshot]

I want to edit my menu. How can I get my main HTML file.. and what is this actually?
I can browse my domain easily. There is not any problem but I want to change something into the HTML code. There is nothing showing. That is just an HTML template. No CMS actually

Comment: What server are you using? What is the config for that server?

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post the code directly as text. That makes it so much easier so work with.